# What is expected to happen if two elements have the same elevation value in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

If an element A has more elevation than another element B, then, A will be above B visually in the layout. Okay, but if they have the same elevation value?

Let's see this example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/red"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/blue"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can see that both views have the same constraints, so one view will be above the other view. What color will I see, red or blue?

I have tested it and I can see that view2 is above to view1 (I can see blue color).
Okay, but I want to ensure that will happen always in all devices. I mean, in conclusion, if both views have the same elevation, will it happen an expected or unexpected behavior? Will Android Studio choose randomly which element is above the other in that case?

Comment: I expect that views with equal elevation will be drawn in the order that they appear in the XML file. See [ViewGroup.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java;drc=b23c8c8e87972380cdf77e6bacbf9ae608ebcf40;l=4417). A stable sort is mentioned there which indicates that the equal sort values are not swapped. You will have to look at this code in relation to _ConstraintLayout_ to satisfy yourself that my first statement is true.

Comment: "I expect that views with equal elevation will be drawn in the order that they appear in the XML file"  -- do you mean that for example if an element A is declared above another element B, that element A will be visually above B or the other way around?

Comment: Drawn in order of appearance in the XML. A will be drawn then B which will cover A.